# Run OpenAI API document example in Node: where do I put sample code?

Tags: node.js, openai-api

**Objective:**
HTML input form that sends a prompt to openai's API and returns a message.

**Completed Successfully:**

- Form on page that calls the route /api
- Post endpoint defined in a routes file: 'api.js'
- Endpoint returns to the web page the expected success message ({msg:"hello world"}).

**Dev Environment:**

- I am using Express with no framework (the example on openai is React, which I npm installed and worked successfully, but now I want to add openai to my existing project).

**Question: How do I call openai?**

Per the documentation page: https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication

**Step 1:**
`npm install openai`

**Step 1 completed:**
The openai folder is in the node_modules folder, as expected.

**Step 2 in docs:**

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "org-sdfds34dsf",
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const response = await openai.listEngines();
```

**Step 2 questions**

- Where do I put this code? If I put it in the route, I get a:
  `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error
- How do I trigger running the openai API endpoint call from within my route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is how you are importing modules

Use

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
```

Instead of

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
```

Comment: import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
const configuration = new Configuration({
  organization: "org-ZZkon15AYML0UypxazbjcHui",
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);


var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('./api/index.pug');
});

router.post('/nlp', function (req, res, next) {

  const response = await openai.listEngines();
  res.send(response);



});


module.exports = router;

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure you are correct, and this is a simple fix. The code above fails. When you say "Put all code at top", which file are you referring to? Do I import it into the route? I put the code at the top of my api.js route file, but don't know if that is correct (I'm assuming not).

Comment: @RonI the code in comment looks fine to me, are you facing the error now as well ?

also what version of node you're using ?

Comment: node --version: v14.16.1

Comment: And yes, same error, thanks!

Comment: @RonI can you try commonJS import style ? 
`const{ Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");`

Comment: can you update your answer, because changing things to const resolved the error message, thanks!