# Where do you put the OpenAI API key

Tags: node.js, openai-api, langchain

I'm putting some langchain code on to a hosted node.js server and I'm at a loss about where to put my OpenAPI API key

```
const http = require('http');
const cors = require("cors");
const { OpenAI } = require("langchain/llms/openai");

const { PDFLoader } = require("langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf");
const { FaissStore } = require("langchain/vectorstores/faiss");
const { OpenAIEmbeddings } = require("langchain/embeddings/openai");
const { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } = require('langchain/text_splitter');

const fs = require('fs');

OpenAI.api_key = '12345.....'


const processSteps = async () => {
// Step One
const loader = new PDFLoader("documents/document.pdf");
const docs = await loader.load();

// Step Two
const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
chunkSize: 1000,
chunkOverlap: 200,
});

// Step Three
const docOutput = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(docs)
let vectorStore = await FaissStore.fromDocuments(docOutput, new OpenAIEmbeddings());

// Step Four
const directory = "documents";
await vectorStore.save(directory);
}

http.createServer(async function(req, res) {
var ret = "Start"
try {
await processSteps();
ret = "All steps completed successfully";
} catch (error) {
console.error('An error occurred:', error);
ret = "An error occurred: " + error;
}

res.writeHead(200, {
'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
});
res.end(ret);
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

When I run the code I get

```
    An error occurred: Error: OpenAI or Azure OpenAI API key not found
```

If I do the code on

[Run OpenAI API document example in Node: where do I put sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73816185/run-openai-api-document-example-in-node-where-do-i-put-sample-code)

```
const configuration = new Configuration({      
    apiKey: '12345.....',
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
```

I get

```
     TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TypeError: Configuration is not a constructor
```

`Configuration` is used to work in previous versions. for example

```
"openai": "^3.3.1"
```

but with the latest package

```
"openai": "^4.12.1"
```

`Configuration` does not exist. that is why you are getting the type error.

if you set environment variable `process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY` and you load them

```
import { config } from "dotenv";
config();
```

that env variable will be automatically picked. so this will be enough:

```
const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings();
```

Comment: It worked- Problem was that I'm using a hosted web service (HostBuddy) and they have their own methods for a Node.JS Server site and I just work with files, no deployment from Visual Studio Code, just a file system.  I had to do some digging there to see how to use dotenv.  They have their own structure to use process.env.PORT which they control.  dotenv was always working fine on my local with OpenAPI keys, but I just could not get it working with a hosted Node.js server account.   99% of AI is constantly changing and 95% of the information is already outdated.  That's what makes it fun.

Answer (score 0):

One of these might be your answer:

```
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";

const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
  azureOpenAIApiKey: "YOUR-API-KEY", // In Node.js defaults to process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY
  azureOpenAIApiVersion: "YOUR-API-VERSION", // In Node.js defaults to process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION
  azureOpenAIApiInstanceName: "{MY_INSTANCE_NAME}", // In Node.js defaults to process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_INSTANCE_NAME
  azureOpenAIApiDeploymentName: "{DEPLOYMENT_NAME}", // In Node.js defaults to process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_EMBEDDINGS_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
});
```

[Azure OpenAI Docs](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/text_embedding/integrations/azure_openai)

You should take a look at the API auth documentation for openai, seems to be a useful resource [JS OpenAI Docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication).

That being said, make sure you've installed and imported everything according to the docs:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
...
const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "YOUR_ORG_ID",
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const response = await openai.listEngines();
...
```

(Additionally, you should note the usage of `process.env.<some_key>`. Your private keys should never be defined in the code itself. Usually they would be provided as environment variables.)